# Trouble with displaying info from getter method

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

QUESTION: I'm trying to find the win percentage (the formula for win percentage is `wins/(wins + loses)`). How do I take the values from wins and loses the user enters and add them to my Sysout function. Every time I run the program it displays:

```
East      W     L     PCT
Braves    45    66    0.000000
Cubs      87    77    0.000000
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the actual values instead of it saying "0.0000000"

```
public class Team {

    // Data fields...
    private int wins;
    private int loses;
    private String teamName;
    private String city;
    private String division;
    private double winPercentage;


    // Getters and setters...
    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    public void setWins(int wins) {
        this.wins = wins;
    }

    public int getLoses() {
        return loses;
    }

    public void setLoses(int loses) {
        this.loses = loses;
    }

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDivision() {
        return division;
    }

    public void setDivision(String division) {
        this.division = division;
    }

    public double getWinPercentage() {
        return wins/(wins + loses);
    }

    public void setWinPercentage(double winPercentage) {
        this.winPercentage = winPercentage;
    }
}

public class PlayoffSelectorClass extends Team{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Team> teams  = new ArrayList<Team>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter team name: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the city " + name + " played in: ");
            String city = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the division " + name + " play in: ");
            String division = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of wins " + name + " has: ");
            Integer wins = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("\nPlease enter the number of losses " + name + " has: ");
            Integer loses = input.nextInt();

            if (i < 5) {
                System.out.println("\nEnter your next team...\n");
            }

            Team team = new Team();
            team.setTeamName(name);
            team.setCity(city);
            team.setDivision(division);
            team.setWins(wins);
            team.setLoses(loses);
            team.setWinPercentage(wins / (wins + loses));

            teams.add(team);

        }

        System.out.println("East    W      L      PCT\n");

        for (Team team : teams) {
            System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\n",team.getTeamName() + "    ", team.getWins() + "   " , team.getLoses(), team.getWinPercentage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an integer division issue (int / int = int).  You will need to either use doubles or case one of the values to double during the division (int / (double)int = double)

Comment: Also since you are calculating the percentages every time you don't need the win percentage variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
public double getWinPercentage() {
    return wins/(wins + loses);
}
```

You are doing  integer division, i.e only keep the int part of the result, and implicitly cast it to a `double`. So for example if:

```
wins = 10;
loses = 20;
```

then `winPercentage == 10/30 == 0.33..` and you only keep the `0` and the cast it to `double`. Hence the `0.0000...` etc 
What you can do instead is:

```
public double getWinPercentage() {
    return wins/(double) (wins + loses);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally understand now. Also, do you know how I can format it to display all my info neatly like how I did at the very top? It keeps printing not aligned together.

Comment: you can try printing a 'tab' character after each word. I think that will do